# Question on the first loaded page of my RESTful Jersey web application

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jersey, web.xml

My RESTful jersey project (dynamic web project) name is "**my-jersey**".

I have resource class defined following method:

```
@Path("/my")
public class resource{
     @GET
     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
     public String sayPlainTextHello() {
           return "Hello Jersey";
     }
    }
```

my **web.xml**:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myjersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/my/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I run my web app in Eclipse. Why the firstly loaded page URL is

**http://localhost:8080/my-jersey/**
which is an **blank**.

**Question 1.** Why it does not display "**Hello jersey**" ?

**Question 2.** If I would like the first loaded page is a html file, how and where to specify this? In **web.xml** ?? How to specify the first load page is **myfirstpage.html**?

**Question 3**. Where should I put this **myfirstpage.html** in the project? Under which directory? (I am using Eclipse dynamic web project to develop the jersey app.)

Answer (score 0):

The @Path annotation provides the path under your application where the resource is located.  In this case http://localhost:8080/my-jersey/my would be the path you would have to use to get "Hello Jersey"

Since this is a standard dynamic web app you set it up like any normal app, the fact that you are also using jersey is immaterial.

Put myfirstpage.html in the welcome-file-list section of web.xml and place the file in the WebContent folder.